Understanding Robert's Proof of extending of the p-adic absolute value to field extensions
I am trying to understand a proof that the extension of the p-adic absolute value to a field extension $K$, given by  $|x| = \sqrt[n]
{|\text{N}_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}(x)}|$ is an absolute value. Here $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}(x)$ is the field norm of $x.$ I'm trying to read Robert's proof from "A Course in p-adic analysis," section 3.4 pp 95 (sorry for the crappy referencing).
I am stuck on his proof of the ultrametric inequality, this section in particular.

and

First, I am confused with "choose $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ with $||x|| = |\lambda|$." I am not sure how we can guarantee such a $\lambda$. I am guessing that it has something to do with the "choose any norm ... with $||K|| = |\mathbb{Q}_p|,$ but I am afraid I do not know what the latter sentence means. Does it mean that we choose $||\cdot||$ such that the set $\{||x|| : x \in K\} = \{|q| : q \in \mathbb{Q}_p\}?$ If yes, how do we know the existence of such an object?
Otherwise, I would be interested in another proof of the ultrametric inequality, provided that it is mostly self contained. I have read Gouvea's (whose is based on Neukirch) and Koblitz, and they don't really achieve what I am after.
Thanks in advance.

the sup norm (suggested in the copied text) has that property

Of course, serves me right, perhaps one should sleep on a problem before posting on stackexchange. In terms of the $||K|| = |\mathbb{Q}_p|$ phrase, is my set equality interpretation correct?

yes, I think that's right

The proof in Gouvea is absolutely not "based on Neukirch": Gouvea's argument (at least starting in the 2nd edition, which I have) is based on the one in Cassels' book Local fields, which relies on completeness of the absolute value on the base field and not on local compactness, so it's a more widely applicable proof.

I am indeed reading the third edition, so it is likely I didn't notice a difference  between the second and third eds. I was inprecise in saying that Gouvea's proof is based on Neukirch. Gouvea claims the proof of his Lemma 6.3.6 (5.3.6 in the second ed) is based on Neukirch, and uses 6.3.6 to prove the above mentioned theorem, which is why I said it was based on Neukirch. Truthfully, I have not looked at Neukirch's argument; I trusted Gouvea attributed the argument correctly.  Could you elaborate on how the argument relies on completeness? I don't follow.

Sorry, I was in error.  When you said "based on Neukirch" I thought you were referring to Neukirch's book Algebraic Number Theory, which came out after Gouvea's earlier editions. And when I wrote that Gouvea's argument is based on the book by Cassels, I was thinking about Gouvea's proof of the equivalence of all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space, which appears earlier in Gouvea (Sect. 6.2 in 3rd edition, Sect. 5.2 in 2nd edition) and is a crucial preliminary result on the way to showing an absolute value on a complete field extends in at most one way to any finite extension field.

Gouvea's book refers to "Neurkich" in the 2nd edition too, and it's to the chapter Neukirch wrote on $p$-adic numbers in the book "Numbers" by Ebbinghaus and many co-authors.

Completeness is used in the construction of an extended absolute value through its reliance on Hensel's lemma (Theorem 6.3.5 in 3rd edition of Gouvea and Theorem 5.3.5 in 2nd edition): the lemma that comes up in the proof is what he uses from Neukirch and is where Hensel's lemma appears.  Completeness is also used in the proof of equivalence of all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space over a field complete for an absolute value: see Prop. 6.2.3 in the 3rd edition of Gouvea and Prop. 5.2.3 in the 2nd edition.
